# Having sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

Tags: python, database, sqlite, telegram-bot

I am trying to create a telegram bot and used code from github.
I had a few issues earlier which are finally solved but can't seem to find a solution for this.

**This is the error I see:**

> self.conn = sqlite3.connect(str(path), timeout=1, check_same_thread=False)
> sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Spotify Downloader\mbot\__main__.py", line 30, in <module>
    Mbot().run()
  File "G:\Spotify Downloader\venv\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\utilities\run.py", line 80, in run
    run(self.start())
  File "G:\Python\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "G:\Spotify Downloader\mbot\__init__.py", line 76, in start
    await super().start()
  File "G:\Spotify Downloader\venv\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\utilities\start.py", line 58, in start
    is_authorized = await self.connect()
  File "G:\Spotify Downloader\venv\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\auth\connect.py", line 40, in connect
    await self.load_session()
  File "G:\Spotify Downloader\venv\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\client.py", line 562, in load_session
    await self.storage.open()
  File "G:\Spotify Downloader\venv\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\storage\file_storage.py", line 58, in open
    self.conn = sqlite3.connect(str(path), timeout=1, check_same_thread=False)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Here is the file of code where error is located:

```
import logging
import os
import sqlite3
from pathlib import Path

from .sqlite_storage import SQLiteStorage

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class FileStorage(SQLiteStorage):
    FILE_EXTENSION = ".session"

    def __init__(self, name: str, workdir: Path):
        super().__init__(name)

        self.database = workdir / (self.name + self.FILE_EXTENSION)

    def update(self):
        version = self.version()

        if version == 1:
            with self.lock, self.conn:
                self.conn.execute("DELETE FROM peers")

            version += 1

        if version == 2:
            with self.lock, self.conn:
                self.conn.execute("ALTER TABLE sessions ADD api_id INTEGER")

            version += 1

        self.version(version)

    async def open(self):
        path = self.database
        file_exists = path.is_file()

        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(str(path), timeout=1, check_same_thread=False)

        if not file_exists:
            self.create()
        else:
            self.update()

        with self.conn:
            try:  # Python 3.6.0 (exactly this version) is bugged and won't successfully execute the vacuum
                self.conn.execute("VACUUM")
            except sqlite3.OperationalError:
                pass

    async def delete(self):
        os.remove(self.database)
```

Please could someone find the issue here...

Comment: self.database = workdir / (self.name + self.FILE_EXTENSION) that looks super illegal to me

Comment: @Lost_coder This same exact code works in heroku but locally it wont in pycharm or vscode something like that.